# Determining chunk offsets in custom binary file formats

Tags: c#, file

I've been studying creating custom binary file formats for application save data. My current system stores component data in separate files because it needs to be able to write/read them at will. I don't want to write a large piece of data if it hasn't changed, or I don't want to read a whole file when all I need is a chunk.

However, I'd like to combine related data into a single binary file, so I've been looking at ways to use an "offset", something that will let me read specific data without reading an entire file.

However, one thing I'm not understanding is how to setup the offset to begin with.

For example, say I want to save a file with some text, and any number of images. From my understanding, I have two options:

1. Write "mini-headers" at every chunk stating its type and length, therefore telling my reader how far to skip.
2. Pre-allocating space for each piece, so I don't have to read a length, but am also wasting space and possibly not leaving enough room.

The first option sounds preferable, assuming I have my facts straight. Are there options I've not listed? Are either of these options better/more efficient?

Comment: Think of a binary file like a hard disk.  You mini headers are directories.  You may also want to (or instead) make a header for the binary file (FAT) that gives offsets to sections of the file.  You can also have text headers (make sure know size) that can be mixed with binary data.  A lot of image formats do this.

Comment: You can also have a table of offsets at the beginning of the file, but then you either have a limit on the number of records, or must jump to a second table of offsets to add another set of records.  Having these tables lets you do tricks like re-writing a record by appending it to the end of file and then updating the beginning of file pointer.  (Writing the offset of the old block to a garbage list to collect later).

Comment: @jdweng Offsets per "chunk" sounds like the best idea. With my current plan I'll have a max of 37 "offsets" per file, but is having to read through 36 "chunk headers" before finding the 37th going to be a performance problem? Given the fact that I know exactly how many chunks I'll have (just not the size of each), maybe the "table of offsets" in the header makes the best sense

Comment: If the chunks are fixed size then just multiply by number of chunks.  Or as I said have the table at beginning of data with the offset of each chunk.